# How to fix issues when I use Z3 API in C# programming?

Tags: c#, z3

I try running example with Z3 API in C# program, but It has a issues below.
[image]

Can you help me solve this problem, please?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the DLL? You know, like the error says?

Comment: I imported Z3.dll into my project, but It don't work and have this problem. :(

Comment: Thats still not enough info for us to help. Is it getting copied to the output? Do you have the right version? This isn't really something strangers on the internet can help with.

Comment: I am using VS Enterprise 2015 and Z3 version 4.1.
I installed with z3-4.1.msi in window 64-bit, and then add new reference into my project C#.
But It don't work. Please what do you want to know about? I can show for you, if you can help me.
Thanks you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you correctly added the reference to the library to your visual studio project. If it's still not working just copy the "z3.dll" next to your executable ( Ex. in the debug folder )

Comment: To use the Microsoft Z3 library in your C# projects follow these steps:

1. Download + install the Z3 package.
2. In the Solution Explorer window right click on the References tree node and select "Add Reference".
3. In the "Add new reference" dialog navigate to the Microsoft.Z3.dll. I find the Microsoft.Z3.dll under c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-4.1\bin on a Windows x64 bit machine

. But It don't work, You told me: " it's still not working just copy the "z3.dll" next to your executable" => where are "Z3.dll" find?

Comment: I suppose the dll is under "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-4.1\bin" like you told

Comment: Oh. I see, I copied DLLs (z3.dll, msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll and vcomp100.dll) into my projects bin folder. But It also don't work. I don't know how to fix it.